# switch genders or gender?

Tags: verbs, nouns, grammatical-number, collocation

Recently I read an article on Wired.com "Apple Hires Hacker Who Helped Save Windows From Security Hell", http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/2012/12/apple-hires-hacker/

Here is a sentence I'm kind of confused:

> Back then, Paget was known as Chris. She switched genders last year.

Why it is switch "genders" instead of "gender"? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

We also say, in American English, at least, that people *switch **sides*** when they change their position about an issue or *switch **parties*** when they, as Charlie Crist, former GOP governor of Florida, just did by becoming a Democrat. *Switched **genders*** is, according to Google Ngrams, a little more frequent than *switched **gender***. It's probably because there are two sides, two major political parties, usually two opinions (pro and anti) about big issues, and two genders. However, both are grammatically and semantically correct. It's a style preference and not a grammar problem.