# Do you change your career or careers?

Tags: expressions

When you change from one thing to another, you say like you change trains, shirts, etc.

How about when you make a career change? Do you say you change your career or you change careers?

Comment: They both sound fine to me - just don't mix them up ("I changed my careers" or "I changed career").

Comment: Related: [switch genders or gender?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93886)

Answer (score 6):

> You say "I changed shirts" or "I changed my shirt".
>
> Similarly, "I changed careers" or "I changed my career".

Of course, the "my" construction can be plural:

> I was wearing two shirts, then I changed my shirts
>
> I was a lawyer and a programmer, then I became a bus driver --> I
>   changed my careers.

You would not say "I changed shirt", so "I changed career" is also not grammatically correct.

Having said that, people do say it, but this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=changed%20career,%20changed%20careers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,changed%20career;,c0;.t1;,changed%20careers;,c0) shows you that "changed careers" is by far the more common way.

Comment: Except if you change your ngram to British English only, [you'll find that "changed career" and "changed careers" are almost equally common in the UK](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=changed+career%2Cchanged+careers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchanged%20career%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchanged%20careers%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: “I changed career” is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Your example of lawyer + Programmer to bus driver would correctly use "careers".  Most people have one career at a time.  In that case, you can say "I changed careers" when you describe the before and after collectively.  However, "I changed my career" would be the correct way to describe changing a single career.