# to move + plural noun

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, transitive-verbs

I'd like to know whether in '[to move countries](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-38653906)' the singular could be used instead, and the productivity of this grammatical structure ('to change schools', for example, is grammatical?). Is it standard AmE?

I've heard 'to move house', can I use the plural, 'to move houses', in this one?

Comment: I guess, from the context, that you intend "to move countries" to mean "move permanently to another country", but it would probably to good to state that explicitly rather than have to rely on a link which could go AWOL. Also, are you asking about "to move country" or "to move houses"?

Comment: Could you provide a full sentence?

Comment: 'Change country' gets many times more Google hits than 'change countries', 'move country' and 'move countries' put together. However, Google Ngrams do not show this disparity. Though Ngrams show that 'move house' far outperforms 'move houses', 'move schools', 'move towns' and  'move countries' slightly outperform 'move school' etc. I think one has to recognise that idiomaticity is fairly unpredictable with these set expressions. Grammaticality is probably better disregarded hereabouts.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Which ones are set expressions? it becomes rather confusing. Move countries has other meanings....does that show up on Ngram? "political movements that seek to move countries to the right", for instance. (That is my statement). How can you ngrm move countries given the ambiguities?

Comment: Somewhat related: [switch genders or gender?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93886/switch-genders-or-gender), [Do you change your career or careers?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147501)

Comment: FWIW, *move countries* [seems to be](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=move+countries%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+move+countries%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmove%20countries%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmove%20countries%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) more of a BrE thing. (I've never heard it used in the US.)

Comment: @Lambie (last query) It's difficult (and I'm not going to put in more effort here), but subtracting the lower graph from the higher one [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=move+countries%2Cmove+countries+to+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmove%20countries%3B%2Cc0) say (and the lower one flatlines in this case) gives a start. (first query) Definition of strings as 'set expressions' depends on collocation analysis, and choice of definition. I'm using the term to refer to 'those in use when alternatives seem equally good choices'.

Answer (score -1):

When you move countries, you are exchanging one for another.  Both countries are relevant to the action and, thus, the plural noun.  However, if I change the field 'country' on a form, then the singular noun is correct as the former country is no longer relevant.

Comment: If I move my house to another location, then I move the house.  If I change from one house to another house, I just moved houses. So the context is key.

Comment: 'if I change the field 'country' on a form'. Thanx for replying, yet could you please elaborate further on that part? I do not understand it. Also, if possible some examples to illustrate it. Academic referances to cap it off.

Comment: Your example of a singular is not quite relevant, since it deals not with the verb to move but with to change.

Comment: But 'move house' idiomatically means 'move from one house to another'. Your explanation is inadequate.